# Regular expression to match and put in categories- R

Tags: r, regex, string, rstudio

I have 3 vectors. One contains text or the actual words/sentences(text), One vector contains the words I want to search for (xreg) and the 3rd vector (categories) contains the categories each text should belong to if a match is found. Here are the 3 vectors:

```
text <- c("Sole Service here", "Freedom to Include","Freedom to Incl","Premier Reg",
"Bankhall","Bankhall","Premier Regiona","St James Play",
"Premier Regional","Health online","Premier Regional",
"Tenet","Health on line","Tenet","Nations","Woolwich",
"Premier Regional","Lifesearch","Nations","Bankhall",
"Premier Regional","Sole Service her","Lifesearch",
"Premier Regional","Sole Service","Nations",
"Sole Service","First Money service","Sole Service",
"Nations wide","Sole Service","Premier Region")

text <- tolower(text)

xreg <- c("sole","freedom","premier","bankhall","james","health","tennet",
          "nations","woolwich","life","money")

categories <- c("SS", "FD", "PR", "BK", "JM", "HT", "TT", "NT", "WW", "LF", "MY")
```

I want to search through the '**text**' vector based on the search words present in the '**xreg**' vector. And then upon finding a match I want to put those words into the category mentioned in the '**categories**' vector.

So something like, look for the word 'sole' and where there is a match note down the index of that word or just simply create a data frame with the words and then a separate column to state the category it should belong too. In the case of 'sole' put it in the 'SS' category. 'freedom' put it in the 'FD' category and so on.

**Solution so far:**
I can search one by one for each keyword and it will tell me the indexes where it finds a match.

```
 reg_func <- function(x){grep(x,text)  
    }
    reg_func("sole")
reg_func("freedom")
```

This will give me the indexes for each matched word, which I can then use to update the categories. Is there a way I can do it quicker? rather then searching one word at a time? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

data: (modified to have a double match in 1. entry und no match last entry)

```
text <- c("Sole Service here, premier", "Freedom to Include","Freedom to Incl","Premier Reg",
          "Bankhall","Bankhall","Premier Regiona","St James Play",
          "Premier Regional","Health online","Premier Regional",
          "Tenet","Health on line","Tenet","Nations","Woolwich",
          "Premier Regional","Lifesearch","Nations","Bankhall",
          "Premier Regional","Sole Service her","Lifesearch",
          "Premier Regional","Sole Service","Nations",
          "Sole Service","First Money service","Sole Service",
          "Nations wide","Sole Service","Premier Region", "no match in here!!!")

#text <- tolower(text) # not needed, use ignore.case = T later

xreg <- c("sole","freedom","premier","bankhall","james","health","tennet",
          "nations","woolwich","life","money")

categories <- c("SS", "FD", "PR", "BK", "JM", "HT", "TT", "NT", "WW", "LF", "MY")
```

code:

```
names(categories) = xreg  # create named vector

ans <- data.frame(text = I(text)) # create a data.frame where you store it all.

ans$xreg_m<-
apply(
    sapply(xreg, function(x) {grepl(x, text, ignore.case = T)}), 1, function(x) xreg[x]
      )
ans$xreg_m[!lengths(ans$xreg_m)] <- NA  # if no match is found. character(0) is returned. I want to have NA instead. character(0) has a length of 0. I'm using this knowledge to find them.

ans$categories_m<-
    sapply(ans$xreg_m, function(x) unique(unname( categories[x] )))
```

result:

```
#                         text        xreg_m categories_m
#1  Sole Service here, premier sole, premier       SS, PR
#2          Freedom to Include       freedom           FD
#3             Freedom to Incl       freedom           FD
#4                 Premier Reg       premier           PR
#5                    Bankhall      bankhall           BK
#6                    Bankhall      bankhall           BK
#7             Premier Regiona       premier           PR
#8               St James Play         james           JM
#9            Premier Regional       premier           PR
#10              Health online        health           HT
#11           Premier Regional       premier           PR
#12                      Tenet            NA           NA
#13             Health on line        health           HT
#14                      Tenet            NA           NA
#15                    Nations       nations           NT
#16                   Woolwich      woolwich           WW
#17           Premier Regional       premier           PR
#18                 Lifesearch          life           LF
#19                    Nations       nations           NT
#20                   Bankhall      bankhall           BK
#21           Premier Regional       premier           PR
#22           Sole Service her          sole           SS
#23                 Lifesearch          life           LF
#24           Premier Regional       premier           PR
#25               Sole Service          sole           SS
#26                    Nations       nations           NT
#27               Sole Service          sole           SS
#28        First Money service         money           MY
#29               Sole Service          sole           SS
#30               Nations wide       nations           NT
#31               Sole Service          sole           SS
#32             Premier Region       premier           PR
#33        no match in here!!!            NA           NA
```

Comment: Thanks - Works just fine @Andre. Can you please explain what your code is doing after you add the text to the data frame? Many Thanks

Comment: Hey, please first run the functions part by part, e.g. run alone `sapply(xreg, function(x) {grepl(x, text, ignore.case = T)})`. Read the manual of every function I use eg `?sapply`, `?apply` ... If anything is then still unclear I'm happy to help you.

Comment: one cool trick im using is using a "named vector" for categories. I can therefore get the right categorie by using the xreg name.

Comment: Yes I just noticed the trick with name. I guess if the keywords and the respective categories are in the same order then you can just use names and call the category name. Cheers for the trick

Comment: The correct and same order of xreg and categorie is of course essential.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining the functions used in @Andre Elrico answer

```
apply(
  sapply(xreg, function(x) {grepl(x, text, ignore.case = T)}), 1, function(x) xreg[x]
)

# Apply each xreg pattern to the text vector and see if there's a match  
# result is TRUE or FALSE gives each index where there is a match
sapply(xreg, function(x) {grepl(x, text, ignore.case = T)})
```

## Result

```
      sole freedom premier bankhall james health tennet nations woolwich  life money
[1,]  TRUE   FALSE    TRUE    FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE    TRUE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE    TRUE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE   FALSE   FALSE     TRUE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE   FALSE   FALSE     TRUE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE    FALSE FALSE FALSE

# Now apply each xreg element to the TRUE's from the previous result 
# and see which element of xreg it matches with
apply(
  sapply(xreg, function(x) {grepl(x, text, ignore.case = T)}), 1, function(x) xreg[x]
)
```

Result

```
[[1]]
[1] "sole"    "premier"

[[2]]
[1] "freedom"

[[3]]
[1] "freedom"

[[4]]
[1] "premier"

[[5]]
[1] "bankhall"

[[6]]
[1] "bankhall"
```

Now to get the categories for each of our matched term (Regex)

```
sapply(ans$xreg_m, function(x) unique(unname( categories[x] )))
```

which says:

```
# Take each element of xreg_m (our matched terms) and 
# see which element in the categories vector it matches with 
#  Then unname the result so you only get the category
```